# How to find duplicate id's in a form?

Tags: html, forms, field

I've created a form with about 800 fields in it. Unknowingly I've given same id for few fields in the form. How to trace them?

Comment: quick solution: http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Provide more details. In what form do you have your HTML form?

Comment: notepad++ or text wrangler find and replace to change them

Comment: Michael, I guess they want to find the duplicates. Search/Replace only works well if you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The **http://validator.w3.org/** will be the handy solution. But using **jquery** you can do something like this:

```
//See your console for duplicate ids

$('[id]').each(function(){
  var id = $('[id="'+this.id+'"]');
  if(id.length>1 && id[0]==this) {
    console.log('Duplicate id '+this.id);
    alert('duplicate found');
  }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you

[Source: Finding duplicate ID’s on an HTML page](http://dev.enekoalonso.com/2011/05/06/finding-duplicate-ids-on-an-html-page/)

> Finding duplicate ID’s on an HTML page
>
> Written by Eneko Alonso on May 6, 2011
>
> Looks like sometimes we forgot element ID’s
> are meant to be unique on a HTML page. Here is a little bit of code I
> just wrote to find duplicate ID’s on a page (run the code on your
> browser’s javascript console):

```
var idList = {};
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('');
for (var i in nodes) {
  if (!isNaN(i) && nodes[i].id) {
    idList[nodes[i].id] = idList[nodes[i].id]? idList[nodes[i].id]+1:1;
  }
}
for (var id in idList) {
  if (idList[id] > 1) console.log("Duplicate id: #" + id);
}
```

Comment: This will work just edit it so that the line, `var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('');`, is changed to `var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');`

Answer (score 1):

I've created an example for you to have a look at, it finds all of the duplicate IDs within a form/element on a page and prints the duplicates ID names to the console.

The array `contains` method was taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/237176/365796).

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="frm">
            <input type="text" id="a" />
            <input type="text" id="b" />
            <input type="text" id="c" />
            <input type="text" id="d" />
            <input type="text" id="e" />
            <input type="text" id="f" />
            <input type="text" id="a" />
            <input type="text" id="h" />
            <input type="text" id="i" />
            <input type="text" id="j" />
            <input type="text" id="d" />
            <input type="text" id="l" />            
        </form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) { //Add a 'contains' method to arrays
            var i = this.length;
            while (i--) {
                if (this[i] === obj) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        frm = document.getElementById('frm'); //Get the form
        els = frm.getElementsByTagName('input'); //Get all inputs within the form

        ids = new Array(els.length); //Create an array to hold the IDs

        for(e = 0; e < els.length; e++) { //Loop through all of the elements
            if(ids.contains(els[e].id)) //If teh array already contains the ID we are on
                console.log('Duplicate: '+els[e].id); //Print 'Duplicate: {ID}' to the console

            ids.push(els[e].id); //Add the ID to the array
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

The above code will output the following:

> Duplicate: a
>
> Duplicate: d

Answer (score 1):

One-ish liner using just array methods:

```
[].map.call(document.querySelectorAll("[id]"), 
     function (e) {
        return e.id;
     }).filter(function(e,i,a) {
        return ((a.lastIndexOf(e) !== i) && !console.log(e));
     })
```

Logs every duplicate and returns an array containing the ids if any were found.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension named Dup-ID which if you install, you just need to press the button to check duplicated ids.
Link of install: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dup-id-scans-html-for-dup/nggpgolddgjmkjioagggmnmddbgedice

Comment: It also prints out all the id-s found on the page.

Answer (score -2):

By defualt [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) has syntax highlighting that if you double click one word to select it, it will highlight all other occurences of the same word. You are going to have to do some (probably a lot) of manual work renaming things, I mean since fields can't come up with their own unique name.

Comment: Better get started. He must have some idea where the duplicates are.